# Why is my web page text and images not aligning on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

[Picture of the problem, text and img don't align][1]
Here are my HTML & CSS file.

As far as I can tell I am missing some information on how to have the documents body and the inline flexbox act together. I thought this mobile specific meta would be enough to help the webpage fluctuate.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .5em;
  margin: 5px;
}

h4 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

img {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 3px solid darkgrey;
  cursor: default;
}

hr {
  border-width: 2;
  border-top: 2px solid lightgray;
  max-width: 960px;
}

.title {
  margin: 6%;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-left: .5rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(142, 152, 161);
}

#verticalline {
  margin: 3%;
}

#edu-exp {
  display: flex;
  margin: 3%;
}

#imageflex {
  display: inline-flexbox;
}
```

```html
<!-- Mobile Specific Metas
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- FONT 
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- CSS
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="AlStyle.css">

<!-- Favicon
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="FAVICON.jpg">

</head>

<body>


  <div id='imageflex'>
    <!-- IMA Educateboiiii
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <div>
      <img src="http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="Mountains." />
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Annapurna Base Camp Summit Trail (4200M) This one was a tough one, luckily cheech and chong had my back</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="Desert." />
      <p>Volcano Mt. Rinjani, Idonesia (4100M) Jumping into the sulfur hot springs in the crater was the bees knees. </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="Self Portrait." />
      <p>Machhapuchhre Base Camp, Nepal (4200M) It was pretty chilly and there were several avalanches but we made it.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="Desert." />
      <p id="PM">Pyramid Moutain, Jasper National Park, Canada. We had a good few days trekking through the park.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to StackOverflow.  Unfortunately the screenshot you attempted to include is missing, which will be important to helping resolve your issue.  Can you please edit and include it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a responsive application, I would suggest that you look into Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/, that is by far one of the easiest routs for someone just starting, or someone not familiar with media queries....like those show above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <style>
        @media screen and (min-width: 980px) /* Desktop */ {
          body {
            ..........
          }
        }

        @media screen  and (max-width: 979px) /* Tablet */ {
          body {
            .........
          }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 500px) /* Mobile */ {
          body {
            .........
          }
        }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try using this minimalist framework](https://milligram.io/). These guys are great, they basically do the work for you in making it mobile friendly. However, this is a shortcut. To me it looks like you're not understanding how flexbox works. In that case, [check this out](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Understanding how these things work is exhausting, but worth it. I would use the minimalist framework, as a just in case.